# AWS cloudformation - Stack exists but with non-updatable status: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/awslabs/codepipeline-nested-cfn
and running into this error after running the following command:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name NestedCFN-CodePipeline --template-body file://codepipeline-cfn-codebuild.yml --parameters file://codepipeline-cfn-codebuild.json --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why?

I deleted all stacks and started from a clean slate and the cloudformation stack gets to this part and fails with the error below:

[image]

Here's my config-prod.json; everything is similar to this repo except I changed the amiID: https://github.com/awslabs/codepipeline-nested-cfn

```
{  
   "Parameters":{  
      "TemplatePath":"TEMPLATE_PATH_PLACEHOLDER",
      "VPCID":"vpc-4d08af25",
      "PrivateSubnet1":"subnet-a2e74bca",
      "PrivateSubnet2":"subnet-3d21c647",
      "PublicSubnet1":"subnet-69e44801",
      "PublicSubnet2":"subnet-c726c1bd",
      "S3BucketName":"nestedcfnbasestack-s3bucket-uvh827b8uyjw",
      "KeyPair":"testKeyName",
      "AMIId":"ami-f63b1193",
      "WebInstanceType":"t2.large",
      "WebMinSize":"1",
      "WebMaxSize":"2",
      "DBSubnetGroup":"nestedcfnbasestack-rdssubnetgroup-q0th4tfkt4m8",
      "DBUsername":"dbadmin",
      "DBPassword":"dbpAssw0rd",
      "DBInstanceType":"db.t2.small",
      "Environment":"prod"
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you run the stack before? Can you provide more details of the error in the events section of CloudFormation?

Comment: If this is the main stack in first creation and couldn't be created successfully, the main stack never deleted but stays in "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" status. You need to delete it yourself in the cloudformation tab.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I'm still trying to figure this out; please click on the image in my updated question above to see the EVENTS log outputs.

Comment: It looks like you are using an embedded template, and something in the embedded template is failing. Try launching the embedded template separately and debugging what is failing in it further.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, the stack was not successfully deployed and, therefore, rolled back. You won't be able to update this stack or even create a new one using the same name.

Find this stack in the [AWS CloudFormation Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/), you might have to adjust the filter to "[Failed](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?#/stacks?filter=failed&tab=resources)" in order to find it.

Then, select the stack and look at the "Events" tab for an error message.

Finally, fix whatever issue that caused the rollback at the first place and delete the stack in order to create a new one with the same name.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I'm still trying to figure this out; please click on the image in my updated question above to see the EVENTS log outputs. The cloudformation template successfully creates a t2.large amazon linux ami instance but then fails with this error which is also in pic above: The following resource(s) failed to create: [DBServer].

Comment: You can have a more detailed error message if you filter by "deleted" stacks and select "Test-NestedCFN-CodePipeline-DatabaseStack...". Then check in the events you should see what's wrong with the [DBServer] resource.

Comment: instead of deleting the stack, you can continue the rollback update (after fixing the underlying issue) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-continueupdaterollback.html